# Can't start mysqld (mariadb) on Fedora, if put a backup into /var/lib/mysql

Tags: fedora, mysql, mariadb

After some terrible actions, I had to reinstall my Fedora (was 20, became 22). Unfortunately, I was unable to made mysqldump, so I backuped /var/lib/mysql folder. Now, I'm trying to put in on the fresh install and it can't start mariadb.service. Probably, the problem in mysql.sock. If it is also copied - systemctl show messages:

```
mysql.sock exists
No process is using /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock, which means it is a garbage, so it will be removed automatically
```

But nothing happens. Also, mariadb simply failed to start and I can't find out the reason.
But if I delete mysql.sock it definitely says, that file is missing and errored.
So, how I can restore my database, at least data? Or... Does exist any other solution to make this all stuff work?

Comment: Is that the only error or warning you see with `journalctl`? After restoring your backup, did you set file contexts correctly? (Try running `touch /.autorelabel` and rebooting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I investigated almost whole day and found solution - problem was in SELinux. If it is powered off - mariadb starts successfully. So, I just needed to configure it, and I did it!